# Can't zoom or navigate Google Maps on Windows phone

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone (a Nokia Lumia) from which I recently encountered an issue. I can't zoom (pinch zoom) or navigate (scrolling with the finger) using Google Maps. It was possible I believe last week or the week before that, but now it's not working anymore.

I can't recall any updates issued in between last working date and now, nor have I fiddled with any options.

I saw in a thread that one could use the options in the browser in order to enable zooming. But this option is not present for me. I use Internet Explorer.

Comment: Having same issue on my nokia lumia 625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from this [thread](http://forums.windowscentral.com/edge/373496-edge-google-maps-problem.html), if it was determined that you are on a desktop version or IE, it will allow zooming to be controlled by mouse. Touch won't work at all. I also found this [blog](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/01/google-maps-windows-phone-and-an-avoidable-mess/) which states that:

> The mobile Web version of Google Maps is optimized for WebKit browsers such as Chrome and Safari. However, since Internet Explorer is not a WebKit browser, Windows Phone devices are not able to access Google Maps for the mobile Web.

The desktop version of Google Maps works just fine in these browsers. It's one thing for Google to say the mobile site isn't tested or supported in the mobile browsers, but the desktop version, at least, shouldn't be off-limits. The desktop version may not be ideal in a mobile browser, but it does work.